# Coverity: How to use cov-import-scm to extract scm data

Tags: perforce, coverity

I need to assign owners to the coverity defects assigned. On the Coverity platform, the scm users are mapped to coverity users. On the Client side, I to run cov-import-scm to gather the scm data but looks like the command is not getting what it wants. The help on the cov-import-scm command is not very intuitive and neither is the usage guide. But, from what I have gathered the command looks like

./set-p4env.bat

./cov-import-scm --scm perforce --dir="" --command-arg="%P4CLIENT%/..."

What does the command need? Anyone had success in executing this or any other way to gather the scm user information ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

cov-import-scm would be run after your cov-build and before your cov-analyze command.

Example script:

```
cov-build --dir $coverity_intermediate_dir_path make
cov-import-scm --dir $coverity_intermediate_dir_path --scm perforce
cov-analyze --dir $coverity_intermediate_dir_path $analyze_options
cov-commit-defects --dir $coverity_intermediate_dir_path --user $coverity_user --password $coverity_password --host $coverity_host --port $coverity_port --stream "$coverity_stream" --description "$BUILD_TAG"
```

You would need to supply values for all the variables there, but that's pretty much what I use.  Depending on how you're running your commands, you might need to supply some command args to the cov-import-scm command.

For mine, using svn, I use:

```
cov-import-scm --dir $coverity_intermediate_dir_path --scm svn --command-arg "--username $svn_user --password $svn_pw --non-interactive --trust-server-cert"
```